# getting empty {} instead of id

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to do update operation in Angular. When I submit after updating it shows random number at the end of the API instead of the particular id number.
The request URL is like this

**Request URL**: http://localhost:4200/api/auth/role/%7B%7D/

Instead it should be http://localhost:4200/api/auth/role/1/

> **service.ts**

```
edit_role(param:any):Observable<any>{
    let body = JSON.stringify(param);
    console.log(body);
    var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('usertoken'));
    var options =  {
        headers: headers
    };
    return this.httpClient.put('api/auth/role/' + body, options)
    .map(success => success)
    .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
}
```

the console is showing an empty `{}`

> **component.ts**

```
editRole(id){
    let editrole: any = {};
    editrole['name'] = this.Editrole.name;
    console.log(editrole);
    let roleid:number;
    roleid = this.Editrole.id;
    this.Authentication.edit_role(editrole).subscribe(res => {
        console.log('edited succesfully'); 
    });
}
```

The console shows `{name:undefined}`

> Html

```
<form> <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roles">
    <label for="text">Role:</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="roles.name" id="text" name="role" #role>
</div> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editRole(role)">Submit</button> </form>
```

Comment: For a start, it's a good idea to have a consistent naming system. Please consider using `camelCase` for methods and name your methods and classes according to what they're supposed to do exactly. (EDIT: You can also simplify your code by using template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: are you assigning value in this.Editrole.name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in component you should change it like this

```
//class variable
editrole: any;

//in constructor
this.editrole={};

//in function
this.editrole={
     name: this.roles.name,
     id: this.roles.id
}

this.Authentication.edit_role(this.editrole).subscribe(res => {
    console.log('edited succesfully'); 
});
```

in service file

```
 let body = param;
return this.httpClient.put('api/auth/role/' + body.id, body ,options)
```

Comment: I'm getting 404 error. The request url shows undefined in the end instead of the id. And the payload is showing an empty object.

Comment: `console.log(this.Editrole)` and check for the new code.

Comment: it is giving an empty { }

Comment: <form>
                <div class="form-group" *ngIf="roles">
                 <label for="text">Role:</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="roles.name" 
                 id="text" name="role" #role>
                </div>
            
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
                (click)="editRole(role)">Submit</button>
               </form>

Comment: remove that `</div>` i guess it is of no use

Comment: check now, i have changed the code. see that object array i defined.